# Offseting GLM Factor R - Standard Errors

Tags: r, glm

Using the built-in `mtcars` data set I've just run the following bit of code:

```
my_mtcars <- mtcars
my_mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(my_mtcars$cyl)
my_mtcars$gear <- as.factor(my_mtcars$gear)
```

Fit a simple GLM: `mpg ~ cyl + gear`

```
my_glm <- glm(mpg ~ cyl + gear, data = my_mtcars)
summary(my_glm)
```

I want to offset `cyl`. If I set offset to be the same as the glm parameter estimates, should get same model in respect of `gear`

```
my_mtcars$cyl_offset <- case_when(
  my_mtcars$cyl == 4 ~ 0,
  my_mtcars$cyl == 6 ~ -6.656,
  my_mtcars$cyl == 8 ~ -10.542
)
```

Fit same model but use offset instead of normal term

```
my_glm <- glm(mpg ~ offset(cyl_offset) + gear, data = my_mtcars)
summary(my_glm)
```

I do indeed get the same parameter estimates (`intercept` + `gear`), and the same residual deviance, but smaller standard errors. I wasn't expecting that - should I have been?

Comment: By using the offset you are fixing the parameter estimate for cyl.  Since there is a non-zero covariance between the parameter estimates in the full model you'll reduce the variance of gear parameter estimates if you fix cyl.  Conversely - if you add colinear parameters to a model you inflate variance, think about it as the opposite of that.

Comment: Just a guess, but since `cyl` is not included in the model (it's only being included to offset the other terms in the model), then it won't be included in the covariance matrix, which is used to calculate the standard errors.

Comment: this is really more suited for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ...